# Calculate if a coordinate is within a string of coordinates

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I have a string of coordinates which create a polygon.

```
278,481,274,531,263,575,982,577,974,561,954,541,863,477,776,485,664,410,650,372,528,372,570,397,590,417,579,465,527,481,426,478,410,461,393,433,377,425,366,426
```

I wish to create a function where I know if the passing coordinate would fall within this polygon or not. For example

```
checkCaluation(577,385) //returns true

checkCaluation(100,100) //returns false
```

But I have no idea where to begin

Comment: Try searching Google for "polygon point intersection".

Comment: "I don't know where to begin" is rarely, if ever a good fit for Stack Overflow

Comment: Yes that’s right Ekesh

Comment: @Andrew: Have you tried doing what Jorge suggested?

Comment: Yes looking at it now Robert. I don’t know the correct terminology so this was helpful

Comment: If you are working in 1D, why does `checkCaluation` take two parameters (did you mean "calculation"? I don't know the word "caluation")?

Comment: You can use this library: https://github.com/substack/point-in-polygon, it does exactly what you want you just need. Note that the polygon structure that you wrote doesn't have the right structure. It needs to be an array of `x`, `y`, coordinates.

Comment: ASDFGerte because the 2 parameters are an x and y coordinate. The long polygon code is drawing x and y coordinates. ie x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y

Comment: I posted some code in order to help you better understand what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we are representing our polygon by an array of `N` points `P` in which `P[i]` and `P[i+1]` are connected (so with zero-based indexing, points `P[0]` and `P[N-1]` are the same).

In order to determine whether a point lies in a polygon, you can use the [winding number algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) which works by computing the sum of the angles between three points, namely, `P[i]`, `p`, and `P[i+1]`, where `P[i]` and `P[i + 1]` form a line of the polygon, and p is the candidate point we are testing.

If the final sum is 360 degrees, the point lies inside the polygon (draw a picture to convince yourself).

Here is some pseudocode (mostly written in C++) that illustrates exactly how you can implement this method.

```
/* Given a line PQ, counterclockwise() returns true if point r lies 
   on the right of the line PQ. */
bool counterclockwise(point p, point q, point r) {
   return true if the cross product of vectors PQ and PR is positive.
   return false otherwise.
} 

/* This function returns the positive angle formed by points a, o, and b. */
double angle(point a, point o, point b) {
   /* Use the following equation:

      theta = arccos(dotproduct(oa, ob)/|oa| * |ob|).

      Here, |.| denotes the norm of a vector. */
}

/* Returns true if the point pt is in the polygon P. */
bool pointInPolygon(point pt, const vector<point> &P) {
   double sum = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < P.size() - 1; i++) {
       if (counterclockwise(pt, P[i], P[i + 1])) { sum += angle(P[i], pt, P[i + 1]); }
       else                                      { sum -= angle(P[i], pt, P[i + 1]); }
   }
   /* fabs() is C++'s absolute value function for floating point values. */
   return fabs(fabs(sum) - 2*PI)) < 0.001;
}
```